# AutoResetEvent clarification

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to clarify how the following code works.I have itemized my doubts to get your reply.

```
class AutoResetEventDemo
{
    static AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("...Main starting...");

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
        (new WaitCallback(CodingInCSharp), autoEvent);

        if(autoEvent.WaitOne(1000, false))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Coding singalled(coding finished)");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timed out waiting for coding"); 
        }

        Console.WriteLine("..Main ending...");

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static void CodingInCSharp(object stateInfo) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Coding Begins.");
        Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(100, 2000));
        Console.WriteLine("Coding Over");
       ((AutoResetEvent)stateInfo).Set();
    }
}
```

1. `static AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);`

   At initial stage signal is set to false.
2. `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(CodingInCSharp), autoEvent);`

   Select a thread from ThreadPool and make that thread to execute CodingInCSharp.
      The purpose of WaitCallback is to execute the method after Main() thread
      finishes its execution.
3. `autoEvent.WaitOne(1000,false)`

   Wait for 1 sec to get the signal from "CodingInCSharp")
   Incase if i use WaitOne(1000,**true**), will it kill the thread it received from
   threadpool?
4. If I did not set `((AutoResetEvent)stateInfo).Set();` will the Main() indefinitely wait for signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WaitCallback is executed in **concurrently** to the Main method as soon as a threadpool thread becomes available.

The Main method waits 1 second for the CodingInCSharp method on the threadpool thread to set the signal. If the signal is set within 1 second, the Main method prints `"Coding singalled(coding finished)"`. If the signal is not set within 1 second, the Main method aborts waiting for the signal and prints `"Timed out waiting for coding"`. In both cases the Main method proceeds to wait for a key to be pressed.

Setting a signal or reaching a timeout does not "kill" a thread.

The Main method will not wait indefinitely if the signal is not set, because waiting for the signal is aborted if the signal is not set within 1 second.