# Stop execution of a method c#

Tags: c#, wpf, methods

How can I able to stop the execution of my method when I click a button?

```
  public void ForEach()
    {
        CreateFolders();

        //For each process get the equivalent processcode
        foreach (string item in Processes)
        {
            ItemValue = item;
            //Get process code for the process under the selected source
            GetActiveProcess();

            #region Switch
            switch (ProcessCode)
            {
                #region DownloadFile
                case "Download File":
                    ForDownloadFile();
                    break;
                #endregion

                #region UnzipFile
                case "Unzip File":
                    ForUnzipFile();

                    break;
                #endregion

                #region RenameFile
                case "Rename File":
                    ForRenameFile();
                    break;
                #endregion

                #region MergeFile
                case "Merge File":
                    ForMergeFile();
                    break;
                #endregion

                #region ZipFile
                case "Zip File":
                    ForZipFile();
                    break;
                #endregion

                #region UploadFile
                case "Upload File":
                    ForUploadFile();
                    break;
                #endregion
            }
            #endregion

        }


    }
```

How can I end my **public void foreach** when I click the stop button. I would like to stop the downloading, or extracting of file etc when ever I click on stop without closing my application.

I've tried using **return** but it continues to execute (Download/ extract etc).

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: @Dan Puzey, I've tried using return but It continues executing. It continues downloading, or extracting etc

Comment: Are you running the code in a background thread?

Comment: Use a BackgroundWorker

Comment: How have you "tried using return?" If it continues processing then I suspect that the implementation of your methods (`ForZipFile`, `ForMergeFile`, etc) are the culprit, in which case you'd need to share that code too.

Comment: @DanPuzey, so you mean I should stop each method in switch (ForZipFile,ForMergeFile etc.)?

Comment: @Blau, Im using BAckgroundWorker

Comment: @DanPuzey, I've solved it by assigning a boolean cancel once it became true then it will return. I put it in all my methods (ForZipFile,ForMergeFile, etc.)

Comment: @MisakiSuzuhara Then use CancelAsync() method and check for CancellationPending worker's property to exit

Comment: @Blau, I've used it but it didn't stop all my methods in executing.

Comment: @MisakiSuzuhara Using worker in your methods lets you check cancellation, but also notify progress too in a safer way, without needing extra properties. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution could be to introduce a test for a variable, and set this variable by pressing the stop button. Please note that this will only work for a WinForm application, for a WPF application, you would need to import system.windows.forms.dll - effectively making it non-wpf.

For example:

```
bool stop = false;

foreach (string item in Processes)
{
    if (stop)
        break;

    //do-your-stuff

    Application.DoEvents(); //this will force the winform app to handle events from the GUI
}

//Add an eventhandler to your stop-button
private void stopButton_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    stop = true;
}
```

But, as suggested by Rabi, it would be much better to introduce some threading to your application. For WPF, a Dispatcher would do wonders. Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for the Idea. I've solved my problem by using a boolean cancel wherein when it became true then it will return. I've use if(cancel == true) return; in every method insde my foreach() method. When I click stop button it will make my cancel true. Thanks.

Comment: simply use if (cancelled) . if (cancel == true) looks like crummy coding practice :)

Answer (score 2):

you cant stop execution of a single method. you can use it by using threads . 
Use a new thread to run the method and on button click signal the thread to stop .
look at this thread - [C# Threading - How to start and stop a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669181/c-sharp-threading-how-to-start-and-stop-a-thread)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Stopping your ForEach() should be easy, but stopping each method you have defined per Case depends on what you're doing in that case.

```
// Defined somewhere which is available to you ForEach() and your Stop button.
// In the stop button set the KeepProcessing to false.
bool KeepProcessing = true;   

foreach (string item in Processes)
{
    if(!KeepProcessing)
         return;

    switch(.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most canonical technique for cancelling execution of a worker thread is a pattern called *Cooperative Cancellation*. [MSDN has a nice article on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Note that this relates to using Task based asynchronous programming.

The gist is similar to this:

```
public void DoWork(IEnumerable<Work> workItems, ref bool cancel)
{
    foreach(thing in workItems)
    {
        //poll to see if you need to abandon the work.
        if(cancel)
            throw new WorkCancelledException(); //or whatever exception you want to use. MSDN shows you a built in one.

        ProcessThing(thing); //process the item. An item is just a unit of work. You dont have to use a collection of work items.
    }
}
```

When your cancel button is pressed, set the cancel boolean. The MSDN example uses a `CancellationToken` and i would recommend it. It is not limited to `Task` implementations.

Why is it cooperative? Both the consuming code and the executing code have to agree on the method of cancellation and agree to cancel the operation when the `cancel` is true.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to Wpf, but I think that using a BackGroundWorker is a right solution if you need to use a thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5483644/906404

```
private readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

// Initialization code
worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
worker.RunWorkerAsync();          // Runs your code in a background thread

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)  
{
    CreateFolders();

    //For each process get the equivalent processcode
    foreach (string item in Processes)
    {

   -->> if (worker.CancellationPending) break;

        ItemValue = item;
        //Get process code for the process under the selected source
        GetActiveProcess();


        ... your code... 

    }
}

void OnClickStopButton(args) {
   worker.CancelAsync();
}
```